# Сделать поиск по массиву php

Tags: php, json

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется выгрузка с массивом. Не могу разобраться как сделать поиск и вывод данных из этого массива.

Допустим нужно сделать поиск по параметру "localized_name" , 
$a = $_POST['hero']; - То что должно искать в массиве.

```
<?
$json = curl_init('https://api.opendota.com/api/heroes');
curl_setopt($json, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($json);
curl_close($json);
$data = json_decode($result, true);
echo '<center>'.'<h3>'.'Все герои DOTA 2'.'</h3>'.'</center>'.'<br />';

$a = $_POST['hero'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++ ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$data[$i][id]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$data[$i][localized_name]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$data[$i][primary_attr]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$data[$i][attack_type]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$data[$i][roles][0]},{$data[$i][roles][1]},{$data[$i][roles][2]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$data[$i][legs]}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: в чем возникла проблема? бежишь в цикле.. если у элемента поле localized_name равно $a - останавливаешь цикл и берешь данные......... а вообще логично было бы брать из API сразу это (если есть такой метод), не выуживая сразу всё

Comment: Я как раз не понимаю как по нему пробежаться , пробовал разные способы. Он мне либо тоже самое возвращает , либо зацикливает 1 и те же данные

Comment: покажи как пробовал (отредактируй вопрос)

Comment: Ну так сразу после `for` поставьте проверку `if($data[$i]['localized_name'] !== $a) continue;'`. Ну и в целом у вас в коде много ужаса...

Comment: Я пробовал через array_search.

rjhdby , я поставил то что Вы написали - в  итоге он вообще не выдает ни каких данных.  В коде много ужаса из-за того что я только начал изучать php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $row) { 
    if($row['localized_name'] !== $a) continue;
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['localized_name']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['primary_attr']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['attack_type']?></td>
        <td><?php echo implode(',',$row['roles'])?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['legs']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!"